Failed to Import Schema from Azure SQL Database to Data Factory
Each time I try to load a table using Azure Data Factory from Azure SQL I run into issue of Loading Schema, I really don't know what is responsible for this. Solutions and Suggestions would be highly appreciated
I tried using my Azure SQL Username and Paaword to login which was successfull but Importing Schema fails after a successfull connection

Your issue may be permission related. Ensure you are connected with a user which has dbmanager or suitable admin role, then execute this:
USE [YourDatabaseName];
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [YourUserName];

